# array of objects в swagger

Tags: swagger

Имеется такая структура JSON:

```
[
  {
    "subject_id": 2,
    "subject_name": "Нейронные сети",
    "lectures": [
      {
        "lecture_id": 1,
        "name": "Введение"
      },
      {
        "lecture_id": 2,
        "name": "Структура нейрона"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Как в swagger задать корректное отображение массива объектов в lectures?
Первый объект в массиве отображается нормально, а на втором вылезает ошибка. Пример моего .yaml-файла

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Learn 
  description: API documentation
  version: 1.0.0

host: localhost:3000
basePath: /
produces:
 - application/json
schemes:
  - http
  - https

paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of subjects and lectures.
      description: Contains id and name of subjects, lectures
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: array
            items: 
              type: object
              properties:
                subject_id:
                  type: integer
                  example: 2
                subject_name:
                  type: string
                  example: "Нейронные сети"
                lectures:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                      lecture_id:
                        type: integer
                        example: 1
                      name:
                        type: string
                        example: Введение
```

Comment: в swagger второй версии нет поля example, емнип

Comment: Да, похоже на то. Щас используется после example. Но вопрос с массивом объектов остается открытым

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил таким образом:

```
                  type: array
                  items:
                    $ref: '#/definitions/Lectures'
                  example:
                    - lecture_id: 1
                      name: Введение
                    - lecture_id: 2
                      name: Структура нейрона


definitions:
  Lectures:
    type: object
    properties:
      lecture_id:
        type: integer
        example: 1
      name:
        type: string
        example: Введение
```